# What is the length of $EF$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ , $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$. It is given that $BC$=8 cm and $AD$=6 cm. If $E$ and $F$ are the mid points of $BD$ and $AC$ respectively, find $EF$.

I tried using the mid point theorem by constructing a line parallel to $AB$, but the equations led nowhere.

Comment: I believe it works out after two applications of the midpoint theorem.

Comment: Hint: from $F$ draw a segment perpendicular to $BC$ .

Comment: It gives a 3-4-5 right triangle. Thank you @Saeed for giving another way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ denote the midpoint of the segment $AB$. Then the midpoint theorem implies that $ME$ has length 3 (by comparison with the length of the segment $AD$), and another application of the midpoint theorem implies that $MF$ has length 4 (by comparison with the length of the segment $BC$). Because $ME$ is parallel to $AD$, $MF$ is parallel to $BC$, and $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$, we have that $ME$ and $MF$ are perpendicular. Thus, $MEF$ is a right triangle with legs of length 3 and 4 so that the hypotenuse $EF$ has length 5.

Comment: I had been drawing the wrong parallel line. I get it now. Thank you @roxas3582 for the solution.

Comment: Ah glad that the answer helped!